# Airflow - Adding a task before tasks in loop that run dependent on the previous task

Tags: airflow, airflow-2.x

I'm trying to get my task dependencies correct. So far I have 8 tasks that are dependent on the previous task which is great, but then I want to have a task run before these tasks first, but I can't seem to get it correct. In the screenshot you'll see 8 tasks itemized_costs_to_s3_0... 1...2........7. but before that I want to have itemized_cost latest only like I have for the traffic line items (see screenshot). This is my code for those 2 tasks:

[image]
how I would like it to look:
[image]

```
l = []
for endpoint in ENDPOINTS:
    latest_only = LatestOnlyOperator(
        task_id=f'{endpoint.name}_latest_only',
    )

    if endpoint.name is 'itemized_costs':
        a = []
        # Load each end points data to S3
        for i in range(0, 8):
            s3 = PToS3Operator(
                task_id=f'{endpoint.name}_to_S3_{i}',
                task_no=f'{int(i)}',
                pool_slots=5,
                endpoint=endpoint
            )
            a.append(s3)
            if i not in [0]:
                a[i-1] >> a[i]

    else:
        s3 = PToS3Operator(
            task_id=f'{endpoint.name}_to_S3',
            pool_slots=5,
            endpoint=endpoint
        )
    latest_only >> s3
```

Comment: can you add drawing of what dependencies you want?

Comment: @EladKalif - updated with image